# Find the match between two ID's

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba

Below the code is to find the match between two ID in excel if it match then put the new value in the new cell. The problem is when debug appear

> “Unable to get find property of WorksheetFunction class".

```
Dim lMatch As Long
For i = 0 To 112
    For j = 0 To 540
    lMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(Cells(2 + i, "A").Value, Cells(2 + j, "H").Value)
        If lMatch > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(2 + i, "B").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(2 + j, "I").Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think WorksheetFunction.Find() is what you need, it's the other Find method that's applied to ranges. How about this?

```
Dim lMatch As Range
For i = 0 To 112
    For j = 0 To 540
    Set lMatch = Cells(2 + i, "H").Find(Cells(2 + i, "A").Value)
        If Not lMatch Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(2 + i, "B").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(2 + j, "I").Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks. It really what I want

Answer (score 4):

I believe `WorksheetFunction.Find()` will throw an error if what you're trying to find doesn't exist.

I suggest using a different function such as `InStr()` to achieve what you seem to be attempting.

Or, if you must, use `On Error` to redirect program flow when it can't find the value.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check Find function correctly below is the correct format of find function 
Find("A",cells(2+i))